# Mysql events table

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am trying to create a script to backup all mysql databases.

This is the command that I am trying :

```
sudo mysqldump -u user -ppassword --all-databases > /tmp/all-database.sql
```

And this is the error that I've got:

```
-- Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly.
```

I added --events and it works.

Why should I add it ? What's special with this table ?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.linuxbrigade.com/warning-skipping-data-table-mysql-event/) sums up your question completely.

I quote:

> If you get this warning when dumping the mysql database, it’s not a bug – MySQL did this on purpose because they wanted people to know that they weren’t dumping the event table. Previous versions did not give the warning.

The table itself is used by the MySQL event scheduler. A link to the documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).